# How to access the static System.IO.File class from an MVC Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file

I try to delete file in controller:

Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult EliminarDocFotoContrato(int? DocFotoID)
{    
DocumentosFotosContrato docFoto = db.DocumentosFotosContrato.Find(DocFotoID);
var nomeDocFoto = docFoto.CaminhoDocFoto;
var dir = Server.MapPath("/uploads");
var path = Path.Combine(dir, nomeDocFoto);
var result = "Documento / Foto apagada.";
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The var nameDocFoto has the name file
The var dir has the directory
And the path has the nameDocFoto + dir (it's correct)

Now i need the code to delete file. Can i help me?
I just try something like this:

```
File.Delete(path);
```

but get this error:

```
Error   2   'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.File(string, string, string)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context D:\VS2010\Projects\MvcTesteLayout\MvcTesteLayout\Controllers\_DadosComerciais\ContratoController.cs 1511    17  MvcTesteLayout
```

Comment: Use `System.IO.File.Delete()`, as `File()` is a method of `Controller`.

Comment: and im using `using System.IO;`

Comment: @CesarMiguel and still have `File()` method from your controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In place of `File.Delete(path)` which, within the context of a controller will use the controllers version of the method; you need to use `System.IO.File.Delete()` exactly like that to access the system input/output version (which is the one you need). If you don't specify `System.IO.File.` before `delete` it will default to the controllers version even if you have a using statement for `System.IO` at the top of your file.